# MongoDB: User authentication using IP

Tags: mysql, mongodb, authentication

I am looking for a user login restriction using client IP. 
As far i know, It can be done easily in MySQL using the following mysql command:

**CREATE USER 'xxx'@'11.11.11.11' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';**

by this mysql will restrict login using xxx username without having client IP 11.11.11.11.

Is there any similar configuration in MongoDB?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Welp, I have the same question and still no answer after 3 years.